# Special characters added extra space that I can’t get rid of

Tags: fonts, formatting, special-characters, symbols, space

I am trying to write a name that has special symbols and stuff in it. I had to replicate it off a picture and think I did a pretty good job but there’s an issue with it. There are spaces that got added with the first and last symbol that I can’t get rid of. i’ll include the name I have been working on below.

『iEnvyメ』

Does anyone know how to get that to now have a space in front of the first and last symbols? I can also include the picture of the name I was trying to replicate if anyone thinks they can replicate it easier then I can.

I had tried to just simply delete the space but it either deleted the symbol or it wouldn’t let me line it up right. I also tried going and trying to find a different symbol that still looked like the one I needed but didn’t have a space. Still couldn’t find much or do much.

Answer (score 0):

The first and last characters in your example are U+300E and U+300F, which East Asian punctuation characters — see https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3000.pdf. These are expected to have a full em width, and that means that there is often going to be extra space to the the left / right in many East Asian fonts — fonts in which punctuation characters (and ASCII characters) have the same width as Chinese ideographs. You can find "proportional" East Asian fonts that allow punctuation characters to have proportional rather than "full" widths. On Windows, for example, this is the difference between the MS Gothic and MS PGothic fonts.

If you want corner bracket characters and can't ensure the text will be displayed with a proportional East Asian font, then you can try some of the symbols in the Miscellaneous Technical block: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf.